# Change Table values with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, html-table

I am displaying information from a MYSQL Database in an HTML Table. There are some fields I want the user to just be able to double click and change on the fly.

It seems to be working fine except I can't figure out how to get the text value from the Select Box. I adapted the code from a snippet that used a textbox so I am struggling a bit with it as a select box.

```
    var select = $(elm).find('select');
    var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

Comment: `option`s have a `.text` property.

Comment: `$(elm+'select option:selected').text()` will give you the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you mix jQuery with vanilla-js:

```
var $select = $(elm).find('select'), /* jQuery */
    select = $select[0], /* vanilla-js */
    value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

Then, if you want to mix them, use

```
var $select = $(elm).find('select'),
    value = $select[0].options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

or

```
var select = $(elm).find('select')[0],
    value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

Another possibility is using only jQuery without vanilla-js, e.g. using `.text()` method.